# How can genital herpes be transmitted even with a condom?

Tags: virus, herpes, genital-herpes

I have read from various sources that, although the use of a condom does reduce the risk of transmission, it does not completely rule it out.

Just how does that happen? Assuming that there are no open lesions and that a condom is worn, does the virus get transmitted through unbroken skin? How? Please back your claims with references as to the exact mechanism of transmission.

PS: I am specifically referring to HSV-2, not HSV-1. I am also not referring to the latest trend in the two strains intermixing due to unprotected oral practices.

Answer (score 2):

HSV-2 can be spread by skin-to-skin contact, so a condom offers limited protection.

https://www.cdc.gov/std/herpes/stdfact-herpes.htm

> Also, herpes virus can be released (shed) from areas of the skin that
>   do not have a visible herpes sore. For these reasons, condoms may not
>   fully protect you from getting herpes.